# Find Index of the First Uppercase character

Tags: c#, string, linq, search

As a C# Novice, currently to find out the index of the first uppercase character in a string I have figured out a way

```
var pos = spam.IndexOf(spam.ToCharArray().First(s => String.Equals(s, char.ToUpper(s))));
```

Functionally the code works fine except that I was having the discomfort of traversing the string twice, once to find the Character and then the Index. Is there any possibility to get the index of the first UpperCase character in one pass using LINQ?

an equivalent way in C++ would be something like

```
std::string::const_iterator itL=find_if(spam.begin(), spam.end(),isupper);
```

an equivalent Python Syntax would be

```
next(i for i,e in enumerate(spam) if e.isupper())
```

Comment: 6000 reputation for a "Novice"

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, 6000 reputations from [tag:python], not C# :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, if you just *want* to do it in `LINQ`, you can try to use something like

```
(from ch in spam.ToArray() where Char.IsUpper(ch) 
         select spam.IndexOf(ch))
```

If you run this against string, say

```
"string spam = "abcdeFgihjklmnopQrstuv";"
```

the result would be: `5, 16`.

This will return expected result.

Comment: Would this be a generator? For example if I apply `First()` on the above expression, would it proceed to evaluate the entire string? Also to me the above generator is quite descent but could you please give a reason (readability/maintainability) that above construct should be avoided?

Comment: @Abhijit: I edited my post, with an example. What about construct, it's only about readability, that I'm perfectly aware often is purely subjective, so the simple `foreach` for **me** seems a little bit more readable, the LINQ, in *this case*. It's a matter of choice. Choose what *you* like.

Comment: As the above returns an IEnumerable, what I wanted to know is if the above expression is a [generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28computer_programming%29#Generator_Expressions) or a [comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension). In my Question I have an example in Python, which should clarify what I am intending.

Comment: @Abhijit: no in *this* case you can not control iteration *behavior in the loop* (cause that what `generator` stands for). Here you query a data, and iterate over it. If you want to do it like that you should use `foreach` and `yield` combination.

Comment: @Abhijit: but you do not need too, in this case, cause the condition over the iteration is done at the first moment you access the result data (and not in moment of the query, they call it `defered execution`), so the *condition* as you tend to mean it, is already applied.

Comment: @Tiger: What I call it, `lazy evaluation` and which will make it a generator.

Comment: You can save the `ToArray()` call, though, as `string` is an `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: I think there is a problem with this code. If the string contains the same upper case letter twice the first index of it will be returned twice because spam.IndexOf(ch) will find the first index each time.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility:

```
string s = "0123aBc";
int rslt = -1;
var ch = s.FirstOrDefault(c => char.IsUpper(c));
if (ch != 0)
    rslt = s.IndexOf(ch);
```

And, if you're only concerned with English:

```
char[] UpperCaseChars = new char[] 
{
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
    'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
    'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
    'Y', 'Z'
};
int rslt = s.IndexOfAny(UpperCaseChars);
```

That's probably going to execute a lot faster than any of the others, and is what I'd use if I were doing this a lot.

Another possibility is to use a regular expression:

```
var match = Regex.Match(s, "\p{Lu}", RegexOptions.None);
int rslt = match.Success ? match.Index : -1;
```

That'll match any Unicode upper case character. If you want just English, change the expression to `"[A-Z]"`.

Answer (score 2):

No need for LINQ:

```
int index = 0;
foreach(Char c in myString)
{
   if(Char.IsUpper(c)) break;
   index++;
}

// index now contains the index of the first upper case character
```

This can be easily converted to an extension method, as @Tigran comments.

Comment: or simply an extension method. LINQ is good but use it with caution not just *everywhere*.

Comment: @Oded: Thanks for your response. I know that this can easily be done through a simple iteration. I was trying to figure out if a suitable functionality is present with LINQ. Off course if none exist, classic `foreach` would do quite well.

Comment: @Abhijit - It is _possible_ in LINQ, but more trouble than worth it (the query would need to keep track of the index etc...)

Comment: @Oded: :-), Can you please take the trouble at least to enlighten the gray matter so novice like me can get the pitfall and avoid such construct.

Comment: @Abhijit - That's just it, I can't think of a nice way to do this in LINQ... And I'd rather not post _bad_ code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer based on @Tigran's but that will return the index of all capitals, even if there are duplicates:

```
from i in Enumerable.Range(0, searchText.Length - 1) 
      where Char.IsUpper(searchText.Chars[i]) select i
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because i often find people dont know:

Select has a way to get the index aswell as the item you are enumerating.
Eventhough it gives a slight extra overhead you could do this:

```
var objectsWithCharAndIndex = myString.Select((c,i)=>new {Char = c,Index = i});
```

then its only a matter of doing:

```
var firstCapitalIndex = objectsWithCharAndIndex.First(o => Char.IsUpper(o.Char)).Index;
```

or return them all

```
var allCapitalIndexes = objectsWithCharAndIndex.Where(o => Char.IsUpper(o.Char)).Select(o=>o.Index);
```

of you could iterate through the objects if you need the char and the index together.

This is just normal Linq syntax, not Linq query syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Linq does not provide an efficient way of doing this out of the box, but you can extend Linq to provide this capability very easily.

If you add this class to your solution:

```
internal static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static int IndexOfNth<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, bool> predicate, int skip = 0)
    {
        var index = 0;
        foreach (var value in enumerable)
        {
            if (predicate(value))
            {
                if (skip-- == 0)
                    return index;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static int IndexOfFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return enumerable.IndexOfNth(predicate);
    }
}
```

Then you can write code like this that will be efficient and only enumerate the string once:

```
var firstUpper = spam[spam.IndexOfFirst(Char.IsUpper)];
```

*Note: this blows up with index out of bounds if the string does not contain any upper case letters so you would need an extra check for `IndexOfFirst` returning `-1`.*

With this implementation you can also find the 2nd upper case letter like this:

```
var secondUpper = spam[spam.IndexOfNth(Char.IsUpper, 1)];
```

And it works with any enumerable not just enumerations of chars, for example

```
var indexOfFirstManager = employees.IndexOfFirst(employee => employee.IsManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Concat(
  str.Select(c => Char.IsUpper(c) ? $" {c}" : $"{c}")
);
```