# Find last substring starting with uppercase letter

Tags: c#, .net, substring

I have a variable containing a string. I want to find the substring starting from the last uppercase letter, like "Hig" below:

```
string str = "AbcDefHig";

string substring = "Hig";
```

Comment: What is the expected result? You want to find `Hig` because that is a substring that starts with an uppercase `H`?

Comment: yes I want find a substring that starts from last Capital letter i.e Hig and ignore AbcDef

Comment: @GhanshyamShukla you should accept tim's answer - it's correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Array.FindLastIndex` and `Char.IsUpper` to get the index:

```
string str = "AbcDefHig";
int lastCapital =  Array.FindLastIndex<char>(str.ToCharArray(), Char.IsUpper);
string result = null;
if (lastCapital >= 0)
   result = str.Substring(lastCapital); // Hig
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string word = "AbcdefHig";
            try
            {
                Console.Write(word.Substring(LastCapital(word)));

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("no capital letter");
            }
        }

      private static int LastCapital(string word)
        {
            for(int i = word.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (Char.IsUpper(word[i]))
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

Comment: Instead of `word.ElementAt(i)` use `word[i]`. Also don't use exceptions for normal workflow. You just need to store the `int` value in a variable and compare it to `-1` before you use `Substring`.

Comment: yeah you are right, this is just for quick ,i will edit

Comment: Now it will throw if the input has no uppercase letters (at `word.Substring(-1)`).

Comment: you can check for exception or whether result is greater than zero ?

Answer (score 0):

you can find all the upper case index by method like:

Source: [Find Index of the First Uppercase character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257711/find-index-of-the-first-uppercase-character)

> ```
> var result = (from ch in spam.ToArray() where Char.IsUpper(ch) 
>          select spam.IndexOf(ch))
> ```
>
> If you run this against string, say
>
> ```
> "string spam = "abcdeFgihjklmnopQrstuv";"
> ```
>
> the result would be: 5, 16.

So by getting the last index from the list - i.e the above example is 16 then you can do `str.Substring(result.Last())`

Comment: `spam.IndexOf(ch)` will return the index of the first occurrence if the input contains the same uppercase character more than once.